# how to define variables after importing excel sheet in R

Tags: r

[image: R excel questions]

i imported exel to R now i do not know how to solve the question, as it is my 1st time with R

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consider going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) post and update your question accordingly. We will be able to help in a much better way if you could post a [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As this looks like an assignment/homework question, and you mention this is your 1st time with R, I think you would benefit more from looking at an in-depth introduction to R than a quick answer here. This site seems to be a good introduction: https://intro2r.com/index.html . The site recommend RStudio which is far more intuitive and easy to use than base R.

There is also often good documentation on basic functions within R itself. Type ? into the console before any command and it will direct you to some helpful information. For example, you may find these useful to get started.

```
?hist
?plot
?min
?max
```